# how to override action bar back button action in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, back-stack

I need to navigate up one more step on back pressed from the action bar back icon. It only takes me to previous back stack entry. How can I override this action so I can go one more step back.
I tried removing the fragment from being added to the backstack and that worked for me. But I cannot remove it from backstack because I need to to be there for some other purpose.

Comment: Usually it is frowned upon to skip a previous fragment in the backstack when pressing back. A back press is supposed to bring you back to the previous fragment and it is what the user expects. Plus, you say you want to keep the fragment you are skipping in the backstack? If you post some code we may be able to help you more!

Comment: Maybe you should use an other on back pressed method in fragment's onResume() method that you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

if your code has this remove it -> addToBackStack(null)